# pdflatex - pseudocode, bibliography entries and figures are strangely interspersed

Tags: graphics, bibliographies, floats, algorithms

I have this pathology:
[image]

The portion of the script looks like this:

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{TotalDuration}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
.
.
.
\begin{figure}[!h]
\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{TotalDurationBarPlotEnhanced}
\end{center}
\end{figure}    

\begin{algorithm}[!htb]
$n \leftarrow \mathrm{new\ node}$ \\
$n.data \leftarrow x$ \\
$n.prev \leftarrow L.sentinel$ \\
$n.next \leftarrow L.sentinel.next$ \\
$L.sentinel.next.prev \leftarrow n$ \\
$L.sentinel.next \leftarrow n$ \\
\caption{\textsc{Add-First}$(L, x)$}
\label{alg:add-first}
\end{algorithm}
.
.
.
\begin{algorithm}[!htb]
$n \leftarrow L.sentinel.prev$ \\
$n.prev.next \leftarrow L.sentinel$ \\
$L.sentinel.prev \leftarrow n.prev$ \\
$n.prev \leftarrow $ \textbf{nil} \\
$n.next \leftarrow $ \textbf{nil} \\
\caption{\textsc{Remove-Last}$(L)$}
\label{alg:remove-last}
\end{algorithm}

\printbibliography
```

Comment: with no example provided it will be hard to say why any float was positioned, but latex will keep `figure` in order and will keep `algorithm` in order but has no constraints between `figure` and `algorithm` (that is why latex has multiple float classes).  As you are severely restricting the placement of figures (not allowing them at the top of a page or bottom of a page or on a page of figures) it is not surprising if latex finds it hard to find a good placement

Comment: Normally latex would never allow an `h` float with just  2 lines of normal text from the bibliography on the page but you have you have used `!` which means "ignore the usual typographic constraints for this float" so you are explicitly allowing this output

Comment: only use `!` in exceptional circumstances and always include `p`  in (almost) all cases if you use the optional argument at all